# Solver between two dates

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying from any date to know what is the date +2 days (excluding weekends).
For example for the 10/09/2021 it will give me the 14/09/2021 (because I don't take the weekend into account)
If we are the 08/09/2021 it will give me the 10/09/2021.

My idea was to do something like this:

```
Import QuantLib as ql
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbolenter 

calculation_date=ql.Date.todaysDate()
solve(np.busday(calculation_date,calculation_date+X),2)
```

Since np.busday returns the number of valid days between two dates.

But it doesn't work, do you guys have any idea how I can retrieve X?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What IS the problem? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to compare two dates and get the number of days between them without weekend.
So i did that :

```py
import datetime

def busday(date1: datetime, date2: datetime):
    """
    :param date1: datetime.datetime
    :param date2: datetime.datetime
    :return: int
    """
    if date1 > date2:
        date1, date2 = date2, date1
    delta = 0
    while date1 <= date2:
        if date1.weekday() not in [5, 6]:
            delta += 1
        date1 += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return delta

if __name__ == '__main__':
    date1 = datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 1)
    date2 = datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 12)
    print(busday(date1, date2))
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer!
Sorry if i'm not clear. I want to add 2 days to any date and get the date+2days excluding the weekend. So for example if we take today +2days, the result will be tuesday because i'm excluding Saturday and Sunday.
If today is Thursday, the result will be Monday
If today is Monday, the result will be Wednesday etc...